# Xamarin.Forms app does not DisplayAlert in UnhandledExceptionEvent

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin.forms, httprequest

I am new to programming and the concept of exception handling.
I think the problem is that I am not handling the exception that is thrown correctly.

I have the problem, that my app keeps crashing when I start it without internet connection.
The exception triggered is:
**System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known.**

```
    protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += App_ConnectivityChanged;
        TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<ThemeViewModel>().ApplyTheme();
        RequestedThemeChanged += App_RequestedThemeChanged;
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += UnexpectedHandler;
    }

    private async void UnexpectedHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!",$"{e.Message}","OK");
    }
```

When I debug I see that it jumps to the UnexpectedHandler but then the app crashes and does not display the alert.

I know it is being thrown because I initialise my API without internet.
**I want the App to start and show the offline LoginPage and a error message saying "no internet".**

Does anyone know where my problem lies?

Comment: the global exception handler is a good way to try to log crashes, but it's generally too late to catch and prevent them, or to display any UI.  You need to add exception handling closer to the source of the problem to effectively deal with them

Comment: You can try to debug and find which line causes the exception and use the `try catch` to deal with it.